# Map is not loading fully using responsive bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css

Map is displaying fully if I give the width in pixels. But if we give the width in % it is loading half of the map only. If I change the window size to smaller and again change to desktop size, map is displaying fully. How can I make it full visible while using the width in % ?

Html code:

```
         <div id="map_wrapper">
            <div class="Box" id="Mab_Big_Main">
                <div class="Box_Content">
            <div id="search_map"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Css Code:

```
      .map_view #map_wrapper {
          width:100%;
          height:471px;
          position:relative;
          z-index:999;
          clear:both;
       }           
      .map_view #search_map {
          height: 440px;
       }
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: how you tried? show us your code.

Comment: I have updated the code. In Css code I have given the width in %. If I give it in pixels it is displaying full map but in % it is displaying well.